# How can I get/extract the name value of a submit button?

Tags: php, form-submit

When I create i form - I do something like this:

```
<form name="form-name" method="post" action="?<?=$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']?>">
    [...some elements...]
    <input type="submit" name="form-name" value="button">
</form>
```

Now I need to get the value of the `name=""` of the submit button, and not the actual `value=""`.
In this case : "form-name".

And here's why:
When I submit a form; I write the action to database - and therefor need the name of the form submitted.

I know I can just have a hidden field with the form name. But I would like to make it simpler by just extracting the name from the submit button because I have a couple of other hidden form elements that I need to add on every single form I create to make my template system work.

And no javascript...

Comment: I don't know if what you're suggesting would make it more simple... Why not just always have the submit with `name="form-name"` and then use the value attribute to store the name?

Comment: the value of the submit button, which becomes the visable name of the button, could be something like "save", "delete", "ok", "deavtivate", "activate" or some other general name. And there could be multiple forms that uses the same button-name (value) - so that gives me not enought information...

Answer (score 1):

So, let's say your HTML form is this:

```
<form name="form-name" method="post" action="">
    <input type="submit" name="form-name" value="button">
</form>
```

And you want to get what is inside `name="form-name"` in this case the `form-name`

Well, then in the PHP side you can, treat the `$_POST` global as associative array, and extract the key from it like this:

```
<?php

  if(isset($_POST)){

  foreach($_POST as $key=>$each){
    echo $key; // this will output "form-name"
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) That's one step closer - But when I have other elements in addition to the submit button - how can I controll from which element I get the name from? like the submit button...

Comment: Well, that sounds like a second question to me :). But, I am sure you can use `if/else` statements to check if `$key` or `$each` is the element for which you want to show the name for or not

Answer (score 0):

I might have come up with a solution to my question...

Here's a example form:

```
<form name="vehicle-vinNr" method="post" action="?<?=$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="hello" value="world" readonly>
    <input type="text" name="element">
    <input type="submit" name="vehicle-vinNr" value="send">
</form>
```

First I need to extract and place the element-names into a new array:

```
<?php
if ($_POST){
    foreach($_POST as $_FORM_ELEMENT_name => $_FORM_ELEMENT_value){
        $_FORM_ELEMENT_names[] = $_FORM_ELEMENT_name;
    }
}
?>
```

In this case the array now contains:

```
hello
element
vehicle-vinNr
```

If the submit-button is, and always is, the last element in the form - this would work:

```
$_FORM_name = end($_FORM_ELEMENT_names);  //  vehicle-vinNr
```

But sometimes the submit-button is not the last element, so I needed to make a change:

If I always start the name of the submit-button with `submit_` - e.g. `submit__vehicle-vinNr` or with multiple submit buttons for different actions like `submit_update__vehicle-vinNr`/`submit_delete_vehicle-vinNr` I can just do this:

```
if ($_POST){
    foreach($_POST as $_FORM_ELEMENT_name => $_FORM_ELEMENT_value){     
        if(strstr($_FORM_ELEMENT_name,'submit_')){
            $_FORM_ELEMENT_submit_name = explode('__',$_FORM_ELEMENT_name);
            $_FORM_name = $_FORM_ELEMENT_submit_name[1];  //  vehicle-vinNr
        }
    }
}
```

This is the solution I came up with - any thoughts?